# Waiting for a set amount of time before executing action

Tags: python

In the if-else statement below, I want the condition GPIO,input(17) has to be different than 0 for at least 5 second until it prints out "COMMUNICATION IS LOST, PLEASE CHECK". Please help me on this issue

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)

try:
        while True:
                if GPIO.input(17):
                        print "GOOD COMMUNICATION"
                else:
                        print "COMMUNICARION IS LOST, PLEASE CHECK"
                sleep (0.1)
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Don't spam tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)

try:
    count = 0
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(17):
            count = 0
            print "GOOD COMMUNICATION"
        else:
            if count == 50:
                print "COMMUNICATION IS LOST, PLEASE CHECK"
            else:
                count += 1
        sleep(0.1)
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

If you mean 17 needs to be 0 for 5 seconds that should work

Comment: Thank you very much!, it work! So the count of Python execute every 100ms?

Comment: The sleep(0.1) line makes the code hold for 100ms (0.1sec) before restarting the while True loop again.

Comment: @AlexTran if my answer is correct please select it as the answer you wanted so others can know it's been answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

While overkill for this project a thread can help here quite a bit so it's here for anyone interested.

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time

class ListenThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, lock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._lock = lock # We lock when we work with our status
        self._terminating = False
        self._status = "CONNECTION NOT MADE"

    def run(self):
        self._seconds = 0
        while True:
            if self._terminating:
                break

            if self._seconds > 5:
                self._lock.acquire()
                self._status = "COMMUNICATION IS LOST, PLEASE CHECK"
                self._lock.release()

            elif GPIO.input(17):
                self._seconds = 0
                self._lock.acquire()
                self._status = "GOOD COMMUNICATION"
                self._lock.release()

            time.sleep(0.5) #interval
            self._seconds += 0.5


    def status(self):
        return self._status

    def end(self):
        self._lock.acquire()
        self._terminating = True;
        self._lock.release()

lock = Lock()
worker = ListenThread(lock)
worker.start()
for i in range(0, 25):
    # Do other things! When we want to check on the status
    # simply ask. Making sure to lock for safety.
    lock.acquire()
    print worker.status()
    lock.release()

    time.sleep(0.3)

worker.end() # Make sure to stop the thread!
```

This will have the same effect except has the usefulness of a thread so we can keep doing work on our main function. (I've replaced the while loop so that it ends but the same could be done as the OP).